# how to data from database in excel format in browser using php

Tags: php, html, excel

I need to display the data in excel format from the database on browser were it will help for filtering in data search.

Comment: then you can create tables with rows  and column(html ) and show in browser

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with html and use a jquery plugin like Datatables that will allow your users to be filtering content as in Excel.

This is the plugin website https://www.datatables.net/

An example of how to use it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({"sPaginationType": "full_numbers"});
});
```

```html
   
    <title>Example 1 - apply dataTable()</title>
      
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">


        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      
      
  </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 4.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td> 4</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td>5.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 6</td>
            <td>Win 98+</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
            <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
            <td>Win XP</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
            <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>1.9</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.0</td>
            <td>OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.5</td>
            <td>OSX.3+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
            <td>Win 98SE+</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.2</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.3</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.4</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.4</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.6</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.8</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Seamonkey 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
            <td>Gnome</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.2</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td>125.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.3</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td>312.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 2.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td>419.3</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 3.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td>522.1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>OmniWeb 5.5</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td>420</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>iPod Touch / iPhone</td>
            <td>iPod</td>
            <td>420.1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td>413</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.2</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.5</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera for Wii</td>
            <td>Wii</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nokia N800</td>
            <td>N800</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS</td>
            <td>8.5</td>
            <td>C/A<sup>1</sup></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.1</td>
            <td>KDE 3.1</td>
            <td>3.1</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.3</td>
            <td>KDE 3.3</td>
            <td>3.3</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.5</td>
            <td>KDE 3.5</td>
            <td>3.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
            <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Links</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Lynx</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>IE Mobile</td>
            <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>PSP browser</td>
            <td>PSP</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Other browsers</td>
            <td>All others</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>U</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
            
        </div>
    </body>
```